# Visual studio 2012 migration (Entity Framework) connection string error

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, migration, connection-string

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, EF, trying to update my database using the console but it fails.
I get a message that the connection string is incorrect although in reality it is fine.

Comment: Zaf, while all information is appreciated, SO is a Q&A site. Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable, but please reword this so that it's a question, then post an answer below.

Comment: Actually, the connection string that your solution uses when it runs in Debug/Release is the connection string from the `app.config` in your `start-up project`, the connection string in a project (non-start-up) is used only for that project.

Comment: Adam - Note taken.
Bob - that was actually what i meant to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to share this piece of info to whomever may need it.

If you get a connection string error, and after checking the actual validity of the string you're still stuck having problems with migration, you might want to try and set in the solution as start up project the project that the DB is updated from (and setup the connection string there like it should be).

Apparently VS uses the config file of the start up project.

Hope this helps.